# symfony2 twig path with parameter url creation

Tags: symfony

i got the following:

```
<a href="{{ path('_be_activatecategory', {'id': category.id, 'active': 1}) }}">Aktivieren</a>
```

creates

> /backend/categories/activate/8/1

and then i got

```
<a href="{{ path('_category', {'id': category.id}) }}">
```

which creates

> /category?id=1

see the difference? what i want is in the second case exactly like in the first:

> /category/1

how can i manage this? why didnt the path() helper creates the correct url with parameters for me?

**EDIT:**

my routing looks like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{id}", name="_category")
 * @Template()
 */
public function categoryAction($id)
{
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the default value for the `active` argument in the route.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure your `routing.yml` file has `'id'` specified in it. In other words, it should look like:

```
_category:
    path: /category/{id}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Twig:

```
{% for l in locations %}

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" id="filled-in-box-{{ l.idLocation }}" />
        <label for="filled-in-box-{{ l.idLocation }}"></label>
    </td>
    <td>{{ l.loc }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.mun }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.pro }}</td>
    <td>{{ l.cou }}</td>
    {#<td>
        {% if l.active == 1  %}
            <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
        {% else %}
            <span class="fa fa-close"></span>
        {% endif %}
    </td>#}
    <td><a href="{{ url('admin_edit_location',{'id': l.idLocation}) }}" class="db-list-edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></a>
    </td>
</tr>{% endfor %}
```

The route `admin_edit_location`:

```
admin_edit_location:
  path: /edit_location/{id}
  defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Admin:editLocation" }
  methods: GET
```

And the controller

```
public function editLocationAction($id){
    // use $id 

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $location = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:locations')->findOneBy(array(
    'id'    => $id
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @Route("/category/{id}", name="_category")
 * @Route("/category/{id}/{active}", name="_be_activatecategory")
 * @Template()
 */
public function categoryAction($id, $active = null)
{ .. }
```

May works.