# twig path() function generating different outcome

Tags: php, symfony, path, annotations, twig

I am trying to add dynamic links to my twig template by calling path() with a parameter.

```
{{ path('single_sale_submit_page', {'id': book['id']}) }}
```

I use annotation in my controller:

```
@Route("/book/{id}", name="single_sale_submit_page")
```

This results in the following url: ../book/?id=123456789. I keep getting the error that my controller needs a mandatory parameter, which is of course true cause the generated url has a different syntax(?).

How can I set up twig in a way that the generated url from path() corresponds to

```
../book/123456789
```

and not

```
../book/?id=123456789
```

EDIT:
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689688/symfony2-twig-path-with-parameter-url-creation) has somewhat the same question as I have.

Comment: Are You use knp pagination?

Comment: No, I am not using KNP Bundle.

Comment: Have you made sure you don't have more than one route definition for "single_sale_submit_page" in your project?

Comment: Try debugging the router and make sure everything looks fine : `php app/console router:debug`

Comment: @cristian Yes I just did. The prefix of the generated URL is fine.

Comment: @paulgv Just tried it, nothing seems abnormal. Any idea why the generated route is different?

Comment: where and when exactly do you see the error/exception? what's the exact error-message? do you face it when you try to render the twig-template?

Comment: @nifr The parameter in the path() has a different outcome. The generated output is 'book/?id=12345' while I want it to be 'book/12345'. My controller isnt accepting ?id=12345 as a parameter because it's a different syntax.

Comment: Have you tried adding a default value for the `id` parameter to your `@Route` annotation? Clear your cache afterwards and report back if the error is gone.

Comment: @nifr Thank you sir! After adding a default value to the annotation in my controller did the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a default value in the annotation to the controller:

```
@Route("/boek/{id}", defaults={"id" = 1}, name="single_sale_submit_page")
```

Clear the cache with:

```
app/console cache:clear
```

After reloading the paths generated by path() will correspond to:

```
../book/123456789
```

and not:

```
../book/?id=123456789
```

Comment: OMG, I was searching for this for days, idk.. maybe weeks :D (in a slightly different situation with yaml and subdomain-routing) This was it. Well, I get it now, but it didn't make sense to me that a default-value would suddenly make a big difference, thus I didn't even try it and instead fought with listeners, subscribers, twig extensions, ect. What an easy fix :D Thank. You. Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and my mistake was in param name, it was "struct-id", and I needed to remove "-" or change it to "struct_id".